# How to delete duplicate data among multiple columns in Excel?

Tags: excel

The table represents keywords of each item. keywords have duplicate entries of each item, and one keyword is placed in one cell, different item can have different number of keywords. how should i delete the duplicates of each item in excel.

for example: 

item keywords

A -> 123 234 456 123 234

B -> 23  456 23  567

and after deleting duplicate keywords, it should be: 

item keywords

A -> 123 456 234

B -> 23 456 567

Comment: You say "keywords have duplicate entries of each item" and then "different item can have different number of keywords", so I'm not sure which contains which. I also can't tell if "A" represents multiple cells or a single cell with multiple ... somethings ... separated by spaces. It also doesn't help that you have labeled the rows with what are typically Excel column headers. Also, what version of Excel?

Comment: In your example, is each keyword in a separate cell? eg: `A1="A"`, `B1="123"`, `C1="234"`, `D1="456"`.... or is it `A1="A"`, `B1="123 234 456 123 234"`

Comment: it is A1="A", B1="123", C1="234", D1="456".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each column contains a keyword, this will go over the rows in a range you can set and it will remove any keywords that appear more than once in that row.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicateKeywords()

Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long 'row iterator
Dim rowRng As Range ' a separate range for each ROW in rng.
Dim c As Long 'column iterator
Dim sKeyword As String
Dim bReview As Boolean

bReview = MsgBox("Do you want to preview which cells will be deleted?", vbYesNo)

Set rng = Range("B13:E18") '<-- change this as necessary for your requirements.

For r = 1 To rng.Rows.Count  'iterate over each ROW in the range

    Set rowRng = rng.Rows(r)

    For c = rowRng.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1 'iterate backwards over the columns, ignoring the first column.

        sKeyword = rowRng.Cells(c).Value 'assign the cell value to a variable

        'Check to see if this keyword exists more than once in this row
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rowRng, sKeyword) > 1 Then
            'if it does, then delete it.
            If bReview Then
                rowRng.Cells(c).Interior.ColorIndex = 39
            Else:
                rowRng.Cells(c).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```